# Cannot Read Property 'split'

Tags: split, undefined, typeerror

There is a plug-in on WP eCommerce Raw, with which I receive an error:

> Blocks Uncaught TypeError in Console: Can not read property 'split' of undefined

Link to site: https://borchuk.top/

I would appreciate any help in regards to solving this problem.

Comment: your site doesn't work, can you please add more detail to what you have tried so far, and when does the mentioned error occur. also your site doesn't seem to work

Comment: _https://borchuk.top/

Comment: My site is not available to you?